# Is it possible to find out through grep how much time grep took to complete a query?

Tags: grep

Sometimes, I use group grep to do an extensive search that might take a few minutes. Is there an option in grep that would allow me to find out how much time grep took to complete the query? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not built into `grep`, but you can wrap it with the `time` command on most Unix-ish systems.

```
$ time grep 'test' *

... results ...
real    0m0.191s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.009s
```

The `real` time is probably the one you want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Not through `grep`; Unix shells provide a `time` builtin (there's also an external version, generally with less detail).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to do that within `grep`, use [time](http://ss64.com/bash/time.html).  That's its exact purpose.

Answer (score 0):

not that I know of, but you can do it with other commands (depending on the platform). For example, in Unix you can use something like `timex`, in linux it would be like `time -p`, in Windows... hmm... not sure on that one

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it

```
grep --help
```

Create an alias or simple script using the following:

> echo $(date +%s) : Start/End